# Custom where can't run

Tags: c#, .net, linq, delegates

```
class Program
{
    private delegate Boolean SomeDelegate(string value);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<string>() { "bill", "david", "john", "daviddd" };

        SomeDelegate AA = A;

        var test2 = data.DoWhere(AA); //This Line Compile is wrong
    }

    public static bool A(string value)
    {
        if (value.StartsWith("d"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } 
}

public static class CustomClass
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DoWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Boolean> predicate)
    {            
        foreach (T item in source) 
        {
            if (predicate.Invoke(item))
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to custom method and condition what data I need. But this code Compile is wrong in `var test2 = data.DoWhere(AA);`

> cannot convert from 'SomeDelegate' to `'System.Func<string, bool>'`

And I don't know How to fix it. Please review my code.

Comment: _Compile is wrong_ What is the error message??

Comment: What's wrong with standard Where method? You can pass nay condition you like.

Comment: and by the way, naming variables and methods is important. Changing from `A` to (e.g.) `StartsWithD` will make your code much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SomeDelegate(AA)` is not `Func<string, bool>`. It should simply be a `DoWhere(A)` in your code. ie:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<string>() { "bill", "david", "john", "daviddd" };      
        var test2 = data.DoWhere(A); //This Line Compile is wrong
    }

    public static bool A(string value)
    {
        if (value.StartsWith("d"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } 
}
```

A simpler way to write it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<string>() { "bill", "david", "john", "daviddd" };
        Func<string, bool> A = value => value.StartsWith("d"); 

        var test2 = data.DoWhere(A);       
    }
}
```

Note: Such a function should check if the value is null.

Comment: no need for a method `DoWhere` and a `Func<string, bool>` variable when you can simply use Linq `Where`. Have a look at my answer below

Comment: @GianPaolo, like you said "when you can simply use Linq Where".   However the method that has the Where might be called from somewhere else with a Func<> for flexibility to be used with different predicates.

Comment: I can agree with having a Func variable for more flexibility if needed, but I see no point in creating the `DoWhere` extension method. If I'm not wrong, it has the same signature of Linq `Where` and it does (or tries to do) the same thing.

Comment: @GianPaolo, probably it just had a testing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast an instance of `SomeDelegate` to a `Func<string, bool>`:

```
var test2 = data.DoWhere(AA); //This Line Compile is wrong
```

Try this instead:

```
var test2 = data.DoWhere(c => AA(c));
```

Or use `Invoke`:

```
var test2 = data.DoWhere(AA.Invoke);
```

Or use a method with same signature like `A`:

```
var test2 = data.DoWhere(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

you said in a comment

> I just want to custom my own condition method

so code can be much easier of the one you wrote:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<string>() { "bill", "david", "john", "daviddd" };

        var stringsStartingWithD = data.Where (s => StarstWithD(s)).ToList();

        var anotherOne = data.Where (s => SomeOtherTest(s)).ToList();
    }

    public static bool StarstWithD(string str)
    {
        if (str.StartsWith("d"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }     

    public static bool SomeOtherTest(string str)
    {
        bool result = false;
        // apply desired logic and return true/false
        //...

        return result;
    } 
}
```

For a simple test as the one you are using, you can also avoid creating the `StartsWithD`method and simply use something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<string>() { "bill", "david", "john", "daviddd" };
        var stringsStartingWithD = data.Where (s => s.StartsWith("d")).ToList();    
    }
```

Your entire code is just two lines now

Comment: Note that the `ToList()` calls can be avoid, if you just plan to iterate over the results